What is the dimension of this set of points?
The following set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is full-dimensional ($n$-dimensional):
$$\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)| 0\leq x_i \leq 1 \text{ for all }i\in[n] \}$$
What is the dimension of the following set - is i $n$-dimensional too?
$$\{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot 1^i,\ldots,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot n^i)| 0\leq x_i \leq 1 \text{ for all }i\in[n] \}$$

The dimension of the image of a linear transformation is equal to its rank.

What is the definition of dimension you are using? Unless I'm mistaken, the image of your transformation is
$$\left[0, \sum_{i=1}^n  1^i\right] \times \ldots \times \left[0, \sum_{i=1}^n n^i\right].$$
If so, this would have both Hausdorff and Minkowski dimension $n$.
